# `HttpClient` error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use `HttpClient` to get responses from server's `API`.

This `API` is something like:

> /api/images/{0}

where `{0}` is a name of an image.
There are only three possible values for image names like `{"green", "red", "blue"}`

I do not know which images are currently present so I make an `API` call to all three images:

> - /api/images/green
> - /api/images/red
> - /api/images/blue

`HttpClient` may return many error messages, but I want to make a special case for:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

**Question:** is it possible to make `HttpClient` return (in this case) error message with just `404`?

Comment: Or maybe it actually does but I cannot find it?

Comment: Please show your `HttpClient` code and what you want to make it "return". You can check the status code of the response...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HttpResponseMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) class contains `StatusCode` property, so why you just don't want to handle it like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    switch (response.StatusCode)
    {
           case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound: { /* return here anything you want on 404 */ } break;
           default: { /* default behavior */ } break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The response object will have a StatusCode property that can be accessed as follows: (note that StatusCode.OK = 200)

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
...
```

Comment: There's no reason to read the entire response before checking the status code - the status code should be checked *before* trying to read the response body to avoid unnecessary work